# Route Error- A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the below error. I have installed npm install react-router-dom on the command prompt. Here is my code for app.js and index.js

Error:

A  is only ever to be used as the child of  element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your  in a .

Please let me know what additionally I have to add to make the code work

```
**App.Js**

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>About</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  );
};
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
              <div>
              <h1>W3Adda - Simple SPA</h1>
                <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <Link to="/contact">Users</Link>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>

                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**index.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
    import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    );

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: I followed the below blog but it gives the error
https://www.w3adda.com/react-js-tutorial/reactjs-router

Answer (score 1):

What is the error when you wrap your Route with a Routes?

```
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />
                <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
              </Routes>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this; (change component to element)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router- 
dom";
function App() {
return (
  <Router>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/user" element={<CreateUser/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);}
```